# How to setup ROS and it's GUI tools in local server and connect to local macbook

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz

I recently started learning ROS and I am having Macbook (MacOS Catalina) which is not ideal for running ROS. So, I decided to install ROS in my local home ubuntu 20.04 desktop server and connect it to my local Macbook, but I was searching for the setup all over the internet but I didn't find any so please help me to set up it.

Answer (score 1):

On a general level, if we're talking about ROS1, then you can use your Macbook to send/receive ROS topics/services/parameters etc. using SSH to/from your Ubuntu server, where ROS master runs. I've mostly used this without GUI, since in my use case I have RViz installed on my client machine that I can use to process/display ROS topics etc., but you can use VNC to gain GUI access to your Ubuntu server as well.

Non-exhaustive list of steps you may need to perform:

1. Getting both server and client machines on the same network.
2. Setting up an SSH server on your Ubuntu machine and an SSH client on your Macbook.
3. Follow the steps listed here to set up the connection between the machines: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup. After you're done here you should be able to run some nodes on the Ubuntu server and receive the topics on your Macbook.
4. Set up VNC if you want to export the entire Ubuntu server session to your Macbook, effectively giving you full GUI access. There should be plenty of VNC servers available that you can find online.

I haven't done too much ROS2 to tell you about that though.